# Creating tfs label from changeset doesn't work

Tags: tfs, changeset, tfvc

I'm trying to create a label from a changeset using the <kbd>Advanced</kbd> -> <kbd>Apply Label</kbd> option, then specifying a changeset version in the version field.

Once I've done this and view the label, the displayed changeset is not the one I selected, and when I drill down into it (right click in source control explorer -> <kbd>Find</kbd> -> <kbd>Find label</kbd> then Edit my new label) the incorrect changeset is displayed (7 instead of 10).

Is it possible to create labels from changesets? Am I missing something or is this a bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's confusing, the screen shows the Changeset version of the file and/or folder at its latest changed revision. This may be an older version than the Changeset you picked.

Only the files that were actually changed in Changeset 10 will actually show a "10" as their changeset number.

For folders this is even worse, as folders generally don't change much, and the changeset number of a folder isn't updated when files are added or removed, possibly showing a much older version.

Try getting the sources at your labelled version and do a compare to the same sources retrieved at their changeset version. They should be identical regardless of what is shown.

Comment: I see it now, I've drilled down into the folders containing the labelled files and can see those with the up to date changeset. Thank you.